# Fatal schannel issue "A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 51"

Tags: windows, schannel

Recently working on a vps `Windows 2012r2` server. Ran into a fatal schannel issue.

`A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 51`.

Tracked this back to a [KB2992611](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2992611)  which was installed on the system. I followed, probably some bad advice although it did resolve the fatal issue, and uninstalled `KB2992611`. I then tried to reinstall the revised `KB2992611` and `KB3018238` and both state `the update is not applicable to your computer`. I am running the Windows-8.1 version of the installs.

`KB3011780` for Kerberos is installed successfully.

All available patches and updates from windows update are installed. MS Baseline Security Analyzer 2.3 reports all available patches are installed.

The question; since the revised updates will not install (`KB2992611` and `KB3018238`) is the system at risk for the original security issue? If so, how can the situation be corrected?

Thanks